# Real method getting executed inspite of mocking

Tags: mockito

I am new to Java unit testing and started using Mockito. I am using doNothing.... but the real method get always executed. Not sure what I am missing.

```
public abstract class MyApplication {
     private Square s;
     private Circle c;

     public MyApplication(Square s, Circle c){
       this.s = s;
       this.c = c;
     }    
     public void firstMethod() {
       System.out.println("Starting first Method");
       secondMethod();
       System.out.println("Ending first Method");
     }

     public void secondMethod() {
       //some business logic here
     }

}

public class SmallApplication extends MyApplication {
     private Square s;
     private Circle c;

     public SmallApplication(Square s, Circle c){
       this.s = s;
       this.c = c;
     }
}

public class MyApplicationTest {

    public void testFirstMethod() {
      Square smock = mock(Square.class);
      Circle cmock = mock(Circle.class);
      SmallApplication app = new SmallApplication(smock, cmock);
      SmallApplication appSpy = spy(app);
      doNothing().when(appSpy).secondMethod();
      appSpy.firstMethod();
   }
}
```

I donot want seconMethod's business logic to be executed but with the above code the second method business logic is always executed. Please help out.

Comment: I copied your code and executed the test. The `secondMethod()` wasn't executed as you expected. Maybe you have solved the issue already?

Comment: Hi Roland, I missed updating the correct code. I have edited the code now. Please let me know what I am missing.

Comment: Hm, the same result, `secondMethod()` is not executed.

Comment: Same with me. `secondMethod()` is not executed. Please take time to prepare a reproducible example.